# how can I make an app that plays internet video such as YouTube?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to play video from my google drive site in my app

I want to make a listview when I press on video it can play in the activity

the video is on the Internet not on sdcard

I tried this code but it does not word yet

this is the code

```
package com.osman.e001;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView v;
    MediaController mediaController;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    public void playvideo(String videopath) {
        Log.e("entered", "playvide");
        Log.e("path is", "" + "https://youtu.be/6ACl8s_tBzE");
        try {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "",
                    "Buffering video...", false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            mediaController = new MediaController(WebViewActivity.this);

            Uri video = Uri.parse("https://youtu.be/6ACl8s_tBzE");
            v.setMediaController(mediaController);
            v.setVideoURI(video);

            v.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    v.start();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not as simple as parsing the URL of the video as a URI. You should take a look at the YouTube API for Android: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: While the android player might resolve your issues, also check the [WebView Class](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) since it will teach you how to access and request acess to data from network adapters, and other necessary info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use youtube channel. You upload videos what you want and get that videos on android app. You can do that with Google Service youtube api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate Youtube library to your project.
Follow this tutorial:
http://createdineden.com/blog/2015/may/12/android-tutorial-how-to-integrate-youtube-videos-into-your-app/

And you just need to provide it the URL of the video you want to play.
Hope it helps!